# Mongodb update of nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection:

```
[
  {
    users: [user2, user4]
  },
  {
    users: [user1, user2, user3]
  },
  {
    users: [user1, user3, user4]
  }
]
```

nested property "users" cannot contain the same user twice.
I find out that user2 is actually the same user as user1, so I update my documents.
My final result should look like this:

```
[
  {
    users: [user1, user4]
  },
  {
    users: [user1, user3]
  },
  {
    users: [user1, user3, user4]
  }
]
```

Document1 is updated: user2 becomes user1.
Document2 is updated: user2 is removed since user1 already exists.
Document3 is not updated.

The order of the users is not important.

How can I achieve this with updateMany?

Comment: Something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lJ1Xn_1hI6T)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$filter` to get array without user2. `$setUnion` with an array [user1] to get the final `users` set

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  users: "user2"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "users": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$users",
              "as": "u",
              "cond": {
                $ne: [
                  "$$u",
                  "user2"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          [
            "user1"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SGOOOJKo-mn)

---

Playground does not allow usage of `updateMany`. You can ignore `{multi: true}` in the playground as it is simply a workaround/alternative to `updateMany`

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the `{multi: true}` trick for playground's lack of `updateMany`.

Answer (score 2):

As a minor variation to [ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77622973/1431750), you can also use `$setDifference` instead of `$filter` to get the array without "user2":

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  users: "user2"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $setUnion: [
          {
            $setDifference: [
              "$users",
              [ "user2" ]
            ]
          },
          [ "user1" ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AO1c_m_VXpd)

And the union and difference can even be flipped around if you're inclined:

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  users: "user2"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $setDifference: [
          {
            $setUnion: [
              "$users",
              [ "user1" ]
            ]
          },
          [ "user2" ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Alt Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LfEiJeZMw1e)

Comment: Great answer, thanks